# Not able to capture keycodes on Android Tv webview app(HTML+Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to develop an android tv app for my website. After doing research I started working with web-view to load my web app that has html-5 and JavaScript in it.

The app loads fine on web view and I can even navigate properly on the Tv Emulator but as soon as I deploy the app on the Nexus Player the app doesn't take the **Enter event** . As I **hit the button A** on the game controller it gives an error on **hitting the A button on the game controller that comes with the Nexus Player**  ------"**You don't have an app that can do this**"

After that I created a dummy app to display the keyevnts on the screen for debugging purpose and that worked fine shoed all the keyevents were being captured.

What I have come to figure out that because it is an htnl5 and javascript based app the NP is not compatible.
I have researched alot on this but could not find anything solid on this as everything appearently . really need a pointer to get it working.

Here is the webview code for loading the webapp:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnKeyListener
{
    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            mButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this),"AndroidFunction");
            // Initialize the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient and set event handlers
            View nonVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
            ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
            //noinspection all
            View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_loading_video, null); // Your own view, read class comments
            webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView) // See all available constructors...
            {
                // Subscribe to standard events, such as onProgressChanged()...
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    // Your code...
                }
            };
            webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback() {
                @Override
                public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
                    // Your code to handle the full-screen change, for example showing and hiding the title bar. Example:
                    if (fullscreen) {
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                            //noinspection all
                            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                            //noinspection all
                            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

            // Navigate anywhere you want, but consider that this classes have only been tested on YouTube's mobile site
            webView.loadUrl("http://html5dev.anorakstech.com/iads/");
            mButton1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:fillContent()");
                }
            });
}
```

Here is the code I am using for getting key events from the Real controller that comes with the nexus player

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Key Pressed:"+keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:fillContent()");

        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Key Down"+keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.v("EA", "Keycode" + event.getKeyCode());
            Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Key Released"+event.getKeyCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                Log.v("EA","Keycode"+event.getKeyCode());
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed Enter"+event.getKeyCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                Log.v("EA","Keycode"+event.getKeyCode());
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 19", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 20", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                Log.v("EA","Pressed 21");
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 21", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 22", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed Camera Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed Home Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed Back Button"+event.getKeyCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent result = new Intent("Complete");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
                finish();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 96", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_B:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 97", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_X:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 99", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y:
                Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "Pressed 100", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**what I am not able to understand here is that It doesnot show any toast from the keydown method but it does show toast when I exit from app for Keycode_Back event which is 4 and for any other keyevents except BACK event it doesnot capture it or  show any toast as per above code either on nexus player or on the Emulator** --Really driving me crazy.

Any suggestions that could point me in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Edit 1:
I can now get the keyevnts in the logcat but it still doesnot show the Toasts and I stille keep getting "**You don't have an app that can do this on button A click**"

Answer (score 0):

[Are there any other components that may be consuming the key events?](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

If not, then remove the `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);`

While this may not be your issue, [from documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/webapps/webview.html#EnablingJavaScript):

> JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by default. You can enable it through the WebSettings attached to your WebView. You can retrieve WebSettings with getSettings(), then enable JavaScript with setJavaScriptEnabled().

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick reply. Java script is already enabled. I still keep getting "You don't have an app that can do this" on Android TV but works fine on Emulator for TV as stated in my edit..Any suggestions..

Comment: @Gdroid Just a heads up, your page `http://html5dev.anorakstech.com/iads/` has broken javascript, fix that first.

Comment: But it works fine on the Android TV emulator. How come? If so, which part probably   could be broken?? The Navigation??

Comment: I am not an expert on JS. It has been developed by some other developer..moreover working fine on TV emulator doesnot pin point anything towards javascript..could still there be a problem with JS?

Comment: It is not because it can work in an environment that the code is correct. javascript is a more "sensitive" language, as in a single error will make it so NO code runs. You are running it in an emulator, with a google chrome client inside. I am running in firefox, and NO CODE executes. `myFunction` is broken, and I will not go into further details, as its a security breach in YOUR code. Finally, in your `onKeyDown` function, add a default statement, and check if it is getting executed.